# Failing to get Financial Transaction report using Amazon MWS Reports API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, reporting-services, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon API for over 2 years and am quite familiar to it. I am trying to request and order this "_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_" report from amazon using Reports' API, and it's generating me the ReportRequestID but never generated any report and i am requesting from last 3 days.
It's status keeps saying submitted but never updates to done status. I have also tried Amazon ScratchPad.

I am requesting many other reports using same Report's API and they works perfect.
Please tell me if anyone is experiencing same problem.

This is the code i am using to request the report:

```
     $sdate = new DateTime('-7 days', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
     $startdate = $sdate->format("Y-m-d\T00:00:00P");

     $edate = new DateTime('-1 days', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
     $enddate = $edate->format("Y-m-d\T23:59:59P");

     $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = $pos['azn_access_key'];
     $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = $pos['azn_secret_access_key'];
     $APPLICATION_NAME = $pos['azn_app_name'];
     $APPLICATION_VERSION = $pos['azn_app_version'];
     $MERCHANT_ID = $pos['azn_merchant_id'];
     $MARKETPLACE_ID = $pos['azn_marketplace_id'];
     $MERCHANT_TOKEN = $pos['azn_merchant_token'];
     $pos_name = $pos['nickname'];
     $pos_id = $pos['id'];
     $serviceURL = $pos['azn_service_url'];

     $config = array(
         'ServiceURL' => $serviceURL,
         'ProxyHost' => null,
         'ProxyPort' => -1,
         'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
     );
     $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $config, $APPLICATION_NAME, $APPLICATION_VERSION);

     $marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($MARKETPLACE_ID));

     //Sends Report Request

     $parameters = array(
         'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
         'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
         'ReportType' => '_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_',
         'ReportOptions' => 'ShowSalesChannel=true',
         'StartDate' => new DateTime($startdate, new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
         'EndDate' => new DateTime($enddate, new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
     );

     $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest($parameters);
     $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest();
     $request->setMarketplaceIdList($marketplaceIdArray);
     $request->setMerchant($MERCHANT_ID);
     $request->setReportType('_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_');
     $request->setReportOptions('ShowSalesChannel=true');

     $request->setStartDate(new DateTime($startdate, new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
     $request->setEndDate(new DateTime($enddate, new DateTimeZone('UTC')));

     $report_requestID = invokeRequestReport($service, $request);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This report can't be requested through the API. When requesting a report, the <Scheduled> tag will tell you if it'll be processed or not. For the GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_ report you will always get <Scheduled>false</Scheduled>.

The alternative is to schedule the report using the user interface, but that leaves you with the only option of monthly, not custom date range reports.